# how to resize images on css with text without overlapping

Tags: html, css, image

Im using cloud9 for a project in school. while using the live preview (small window pane) my images fit accordingly however when I maximize my screen browser my images are stacked on each other and the dimensions have increased. Ideally I would like my text to be on the left hand side and my images to be on right side and resize accordingly so that they still look appropriate despite small or large screen. I've messed with the pixels, width,height, used % instead of pixels as well as adjusting margins and padding. I'm using HTML/CSS only! can anyone point me to the right direction or recommend a reading that explains how to manipulate CSS image sizing? Iv'e read w3schools and other blogs, no luck yet.

Comment: Please consider to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

If your image sizes are declared in %, that would be why they get larger when the screen does. As for overlapping, check to see how they're positioned. If they're positioned in terms of measuring units rather than %, that wouldn't resize with the screen, causing the overlap. I can't provide a specific fix without seeing any of the source code.

Comment: my CSS:
.lean    {
   border-style: solid;
    border-color: #091D34;
    border-radius: 8px;
   float:right;
    width: 10%;
     margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

Comment: here I've changed to 200px but still get same result:
.lean    {
   border-style: solid;
    border-color: #091D34;
    border-radius: 8px;
   float:right;
    width: 200px;
     margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

Comment: Do you have an external link to the project so we can see it in action?